# PHP post always ignores the last table value

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I have a delete button name="action" that correctly goes to a switch/case for `value="Delete"`, and it retrieves proper table values `$_POST['fundid']` for top table `value[record #1]` but ignores it for last table `value[record #2]`. Table code:

```
while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($fund_info_result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['coafund'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['fundid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='fundid' name='fundid' value=" . $row['fundid'] . " />";

    echo "<td>" . $row['shortdesc'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['longdesc'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></td></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

PHP code grabs value of first record, but ignores second[last] record:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
case 'Delete':
    $fundid_record = $_POST['fundid'];
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.alert("<?php echo $fundid_record;?>");
        </script>
    <?php
break;
}
```

A sample of the generated HTML looks like this:

```
<tbody>
  <form id='table_data1' action='' method='post'>
  <tr>
    <td>139</td>
    <td>14966</td>
    <input type='hidden' id='14966' name='fundid' value=14966 />
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td>Administration</td>
    <td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></td>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </form>
  <form id='table_data1' action='' method='post'>
    <tr>
      <td>140</td>
      <td>14967</td>
      <input type='hidden' id='14967' name='fundid' value=14967 />
      <td>Services</td>
      <td>Services</td>
      <td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></td>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</tbody>
```

Another user ticket here helped me at least grab the value properly, using form tag for each record, and hidden value, but very confused why it ignores last record of the table. Please help.

Comment: `id='fundid'` is not a good idea. IDs must be unique to each HTML element. Since you're creating this via a loop, if it loops twice or more that ID will be used twice or more on the final page, making the 2nd and subsequent elements invalid according to the HTML spec.

Comment: Anyway, not sure what you mean by "ignores the last record"? You mean When you click "Delete" on the last table row, it does not submit the correct value? Have you checked your browser's network tab to see what is actually being submitted in the postback request? Does it send the expected value to the server?

Comment: changed it to: id='" . $row['fundid'] . "'; still the same thing: press Delete on 2nd row and instead of window.alert(the value) the submit isset simply reloads the page anew. the Chrome browser Network tab reveals no var name that i recognize. browser log[via chrome://net-export/] 5867 lines and nowhere is 'fundid' mentioned. on 1st row, ea time it goes through ISSET code, finds "case: 'Delete':", pops up the value, then reloads the page remembering select values from before. but Delete on 2nd value, page reloads from scratch - so it ignores the submitting of that element.  #scratchinghead

Comment: can you show the actual HTML that gets output by the page (as opposed to the PHP that creates it)? Do a View Source in your browser to see it.

Comment: i was looking at code.... so, i put the form tag just inside <tbody>, yet see here how form tag is nested[?]:
 <tbody><tr><td>139</td><td>14970</td><input type="hidden" id="14970" name="fundid" value="14970"><td>Admin</td><td>Administration</td><td><input type="submit" id="delete" name="action" value="Delete"></td></tr><form id="table_data1" action="" method="post"></form><tr><td>140</td><td>15056</td><input type="hidden" id="15056" name="fundid" value="15056"><td>Services</td><td>Services</td><td><input type="submit" id="delete" name="action" value="Delete"></td></tr></tbody>

Comment: CORRECTION[that was F12 dev tools] here is View Source: <tbody><form id='table_data1' action='' method='post'><tr><td>139</td><td>14966</td><input type='hidden' id='14966' name='fundid' value=14966 /><td>Admin</td><td>Administration</td><td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></td></td></tr></form><form id='table_data1' action='' method='post'><tr><td>140</td><td>14967</td><input type='hidden' id='14967' name='fundid' value=14967 /><td>Services</td><td>Services</td><td><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></td></td></tr></form></tbody>

Comment: please see my answer below. It helped me spot that you're creating invalid HTML.

Comment: I've added the output of view source to the question for clarity for future readers. In some ways though the F12 version is arguably more accurate / useful because it shows how the browser is treating your form in reality

Answer (score 2):

You are creating invalid HTML markup. The only thing that can be a child of a `<tbody>` is a `<tr>`, and the only things that can be a child of a `<tr>` is a `<th>` or `<td>`. Putting your form and input code within the table but outside a table cell is invalid. Many browsers will shift markup like this outside your table, which will cause the form to be incorrectly created, and is almost certainly the cause of the strange behaviour you're seeing.

Also you close one of the `<td>`s twice (`</td></td>`) which isn't helping either.

This should fix it:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['coafund'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fundid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['shortdesc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['longdesc'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><form action='' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='fundid' value=" . $row['fundid'] . " /><input type='submit' id='delete' name='action' value='Delete' /></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: actually, no. that exact code produces same effect. SO i hard-coded few extra lines, and the behavior is actually - it grabs only row1 value, not subsequent rows.

Comment: many thx for efforts! more input: i have form1 with select boxes, and Submit - produces the table, and then each row with respective Delete buttons. each Delete button is inside its form. <form...><input...Delete /></form>... then, wrapper form closes </form>. only when outside form wraps the dynamic table, does even just row1 get submitted. still, rows 2+ do not even submit. in case this helps. anyway thx again 8}

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/k3f5-7rju shows it working the way I suggested. It's hard to know what's wrong with your code. Perhaps there is some detail you have omitted?

Comment: I had to complete the PHP part for it to make it work properly, I was assuming that was just a typo in the question though? Otherwise it would never have worked for any of the values.

Comment: WOW thx for that, interesting to see it work! the f12 dev tools shows the form by itself, view source shows forms in their proper places tucked inside the value's td tag, as coded. i will chop down my code [it's inside a joomla/jumi wrapper so i need to keep it in context :/] - but i cannot ask for much more, thx for the phpfiddle!

Comment: no problem, happy to help. Please consider marking it as accepted if you feel it answers the question as given (which I believe it does) :-)

Comment: hi, AD, your answer helped me realize that the context of my situation warranted that i create a form for each submit with accompanying hidden values, passed to an isset. so, your phpfiddle got me unstuck - was not the all-encompassing solution but it bumped on the lightbulb. at first i had nested forms and things [including i] got confused. once i fixed then on to next step/got busy. happy to mark "accepted" if i've not already/let me know how, if i need to. thx again!

Answer (score 1):

A `var_dump()` of your `$_POST` could offer useful information.

From what I see, you are using static values in `id` attributes for elements inserted in a loop. That's a bad idea whatever happens next, since an id is supposed to exist once and only once in a single page. You should at least increment a value each time the loop iterates and append that value to your id so that it's unic, or not use an id at all.

I don't have enough information to be sure about it, but I in fact encountered that same problem of yours not so long ago, and the cause was precisely that one `id` was used several times in different `form` elements.

Hope it helps and feel free to add some logs if it doesn't.

Comment: $fundid_record = $_POST['fundid']; $fundid_record = var_dump($_POST['fundid']); - this pops up but displays blank. $_POST['fundid'] displays value of record#1, but the var_dump does not provide output.